# Memory Leak in Titanium tabbed iPhone application

Tags: javascript, iphone, memory-leaks, titanium, titanium-mobile

this has been giving me a headache for a couple weeks now -- hope somebody can help. I'm building an app for iOs 5.0, using the 2.1.4 SDK in Titanium mobile. My app pulls data from a database, and displays it in a scrollableview using labels and a table. I've noticed that it crashes after a while, and according to instruments, the views within the scrollableView, along with the labels and tableviews, are never released from memory. I use a lot of commonJS, and my code looks someting like this (stripped down):

**The ApplicationWindow module, which I call from app.js**

```
function ApplicationWindow(title) {
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:title,
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height:44,
    width:200,
    title:L('openWindow'),
    top:20
});
self.add(button);

var QuizWindow = require('/ui/common/QuizWindow');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //containingTab attribute must be set by parent tab group on
    //the window for this work
    qw = new QuizWindow({title: 'KCT', backgroundColor: 'white', navBarHidden: true, tabBarHidden: true});
    self.containingTab.open(qw);
});

return self;
};

module.exports = ApplicationWindow;
```

**I then call the QuizWindow module:**

```
function QuizWindow(args){
var instance = Ti.UI.createWindow(args);
var QuestionView = require('/ui/common/QuestionView');

var db = Ti.Database.install("/kct.sqlite","kct");
var q = db.execute("SELECT * FROM questions");

var sv = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    bottom: 40
});

while(q.isValidRow()){
    var id = q.fieldByName("qid");
    var question = q.fieldByName("q");
    var set = q.fieldByName("set");
    var info = q.fieldByName("info");

    var v = new QuestionView(id,set,question,info);
    sv.addView(v);
    q.next();
}

q.close();
db.close();

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height:44,
    width:200,
    title:"Close",
    bottom:10
});

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    instance.close({animation: true});
});

instance.add(sv);
instance.add(button);
return instance;
};
module.exports = QuizWindow;
```

**and this is the QuestionView:**

```
function QuestionView (id,set,question,infolert) {
var qview = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    questionSet: set,
    questionID: id,
    info: infolert,
    isAnswered: false       
});

var qLabel = gui.Header(question);
qLabel.top = 5;
qLabel.left = 10;
qLabel.right = 10;
qLabel.color = "#3B3B3B";
qLabel.font = {fontSize: gui.defaultFontSize+4, fontWeight: 'bold'};

var dcalc = (qLabel.text.length / 30) * ((gui.defaultFontSize+4)*1.2) + 5;

var answView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    top: dcalc,
    _parent: qview
});

var changeheight = function(e) {
    var lheight = e.source.rect.height;
    if(lheight && lheight > 10) answView.top = lheight + 5;
    return;
};

qLabel.addEventListener('postlayout', changeheight);


qview.add(qLabel);
qview.add(answView);

return qview;

}
 module.exports = QuestionView;
```

I originally had some code in there to pull data for the answers from the database, and fill the tableView with that, but I removed it for the sake of brevity. Even without that, nothing gets released. I'm really at a loss here, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I solved it. It was this:

```
var answView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    (...)
    _parent: qview
});
```

referencing the view in the answer table kept it, and all its children, from being released. Once I removed that, they get released simply by closing the window. Hope that's useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at my Gist. By using this you can solve out the memory issue to great extend. Just include the class in your project and use it like this.

https://gist.github.com/3898340

```
var mem = new MemoryClean();
    mem.clean(tableView);
    mem.clean(headerView);
    mem.clean(footerView);
    mem = null;
```

Here is what i have been using.

```
function openAppointments(e) {
    var mem = new MemoryClean();
    mem.clean(headerView);
    mem.clean(footerView);
    mem = null;
    win.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried pasing the mem with the constructor, adding every view, label and table to it, and setting it to null when closing the window, but that didn't work out. They're still stacking up. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, do you have any examples on how to use it?

Comment: what did the info statements print in the console. Ti.API.warn("This is our Memory" +Ti.Platform.availableMemory);. I think when closing the window, it should get released.

Comment: It kept giving me an error, without releasing memory...maybe that's just me.