# Memory leak in CommonJS

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, commonjs

This is the JS code used:

```
//values stored in properties
    var CONFIG = (function() {
         var properties = {
             'property1': 'value1',
             'property2': 'value2'
         };

         return module.exports = {
            get: function(name) { return properties[name]; }
        };
    })();
```

Here is my Config Global Object and i am using it my other file in this manner.

```
var Model = (function() {   
    function checkData() {      
        var CONFIG = require('/library/utils/Constants');       
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString(CONFIG.get('property1'), "0");
        //Creating JsonClient
        var JsonClient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();       
        JsonClient.onload = function() {
            Titanium.App.Properties.setString(CONFIG.get('property2'),'false');
        };
        JsonClient.onerror = function(e) {

        };
    };          
    return module.exports =  {
        checkData:checkData         
    }
})();
```

1. Will my Model class cause memory leak, just because i am using the
   CONFIG object in the model  ? `JSON onload and Model Class.`
2. How to track memory leaks or learn what causes memory leak ?

Comment: there is no point using the module pattern and selfexecuting functions if the js env you are working in supports modules , in the first exemple you are already creating a closure with the property variable, You are doing a lot of unecessary stuffs in your code yet you are worried about memory leaks? closures are expensive in javascript function calls too.

Comment: @mpm: can u change the code and post on how it can improve.

Comment: Why are you worried about memory leaks here? Of course the `CONFIG` needs to be holded in memory as long as the onload listener is available.

Comment: @Bergi: My application is causing memory related issues. that's why i am checking which part of code is causing memory leaks. Will the CONFIG variable be garbage collected once the onload listener's callback finishes.

Comment: @theJava: Will the whole `JsonClient` be collected after it is done? Are there references to it from outside, and does your garbage collector resolve the circular references correctly?

Comment: @Bergi: There are no references to it from outside.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory Leak in Titanium tabbed iPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972019/memory-leak-in-titanium-tabbed-iphone-application)